# No member named 'read' in 'metal::texturecube'

Tags: ios, fragment-shader, metal

According to [Apple's Metal shading language specification](https://developer.apple.com/metal/Metal-Shading-Language-Specification.pdf#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014364), texture cubes have a read method,

```
read(uint2 coord, uint face, uint lod = 0) const
```

However, when I try to build this shader, I get a compiler error,

```
fragment half4 passFragment(VertexInOut inFrag [[stage_in]],
                            texturecube<float, access::read> tex [[ texture(0) ]])
{
    float4 out = tex.read(uint2(0,0), uint(0));
    return half4(out);
}
```

The error is,

```
No member named 'read' in 'metal::texturecube<float, metal::access::read>'
```

If I remove the access qualifier, then I get,

```
No member named 'read' in 'metal::texturecube<float, metal::access::sample>'
```

I also tried changing the type from float to int or short, but I get the same error. Frustrating that there's no header to look at...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that `texturecube::read()` is only available on macOS.

There are, in fact, headers available. Look in /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/usr/lib/clang/3.5/include/metal.

In the metal_texture header, you'll see that the declaration of `read()` is inside of a preprocessor conditional (`#if`) and is only declared if the macro `__HAVE_TEXTURE_CUBE_READ__` is defined. On macOS, that's defined in the metal_config header. On iOS, it's not defined.